# RavenDB indices chains

Tags: c#, .net, mapreduce, nosql, ravendb

Is it possible to use an output of one index as an input for another?

Something like:

```
 public class ChainedIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<InputIndex, InputIndexOutputType, ReduceResult>
 {
   //blahblahblah
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can now do this.

- Enable the [Scripted Index Results bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/bundles/scripted-index-results)
- Write your first index, for example - a map/reduce index.
- Write a script that writes the result back to another document.
- Write a new index against those documents.

As changes to the original documents are indexed, the resulting changes get written to new documents, which then get indexed.  Repeat if desired, just be careful not to create an endless loop.

This is a new feature for RavenDB 2.5.  Oren describes it in [this video](http://youtu.be/QaCo5Ec_rVo?t=21m36s) at 21:36.